# Prove orthogonal group is generated by rotations and reflections

Tags: abstract-algebra, orthogonality

How can I use induction to show that

$O(n)$ is generated by rotations and reflections in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I know  case $n=1$ is trivial, but I have no idea about $n>1$.

Can someone give me details?

What textbooks or references could I find this?

I have referred to Artin's algebra, but I still can't prove it.

Comment: Hint: Since $A$ is orthogonal, if $A (V) \subset V$ for some subspace, then also $A(V^\perp)\subset V^\perp$.